# PHP not running scripts, downloading them instead

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian

I know, a very typical problem, but I run out of ideas. Yes, the module is installed:

```
# aptitude search libapache2-mod-php5
i   libapache2-mod-php5                                                         - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)                       
p   libapache2-mod-php5filter                                                   - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (apache 2 filter module)
```

and enabled:

```
# ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 2011-08-31 13:49 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf -> ../mods-available/php5.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 2011-08-31 13:49 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load -> ../mods-available/php5.load

# cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3 .php5
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>

# cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

Apache claims PHP is lodade:

```
# apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_html_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

There's no .htaccess in the document root and the 404 shows PHP as present:

> Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny13 with Suhosin-Patch proxy_html/3.0.0 Server at wiki.example.com Port 80

The logs shows no errors.

Any ideas what else to check?

Comment: A bit obvious, but...did you do a full apache restart (stop/start) instead of a graceful or even 'restart'?

Comment: @DTest, thanks for the comment. Yes, I did several stop and starts, explicitly.

Comment: Your php files are not inside the PassengerRoot folder, right?

Comment: @j.p updated my answer for logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your apache config is loading it, eg:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

Then, make sure Apache knows to interpret .php files, eg

```
AddType text/html .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

**EDIT**

You mention the error logs contain no errors. What is the status code of the requests to the .php scripts? (200, 500,etc)

In your php.ini file, check the settings for `log_errors`, `display_errors`, and [`error_log`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log). If errors are logging, they will be in the location specified by `error_log`. I think this the default behavior (logging, not displaying to screen).

If your app needs MySQL, make sure you installed the php5-mysql package too. Same for any other needed module.

Comment: Yes, they are loaded, I added the info to the question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @J.P what's the output of `httpd -M` (or equivalent on Debian)

Comment: what's httpd -M supposed to do?

Comment: @j.p Print a list of loaded modules apache sees. Just wanting to make sure php is loaded...grasping I guess!

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: @j.p Ok, "The logs shows no errors." which logs apache? Have you checked php error logs? 500 server errors might cause scripts to be downloaded instead of parsed.

Comment: I only checked the apache error and access logs. Does PHP keep logs somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have PHP and Passenger in the same location at the same time using the handler modules (each request is only "handled" once, and in this case, Passenger is handling the request).  If you must serve PHP from your rails app for some reason, you need to either make a specific Location or Directory and [disable Passenger in that location](http://www.abletech.co.nz/2009/06/serving-php-from-a-rails-app-with-passenger/) like so:

```
<Directory /var/www/php/goes/here>
   PassengerEnabled off
</Directory>
```

or

```
<Location /php/goes/here>
   PassengerEnabled off
</Location>
```

[More here in the official docs](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengerenabled_lt_on_off_gt)

[It looks like](http://markmail.org/message/62whfimjff2abhaa) turning off PassengerEnabled does not enable DirectoryIndex, so you may need to manually rewrite from ^/php/goes/here/$ to /php/goes/here/index.php

Also, it looks like using [PassengerHighPerformance](http://www.conandalton.net/2010/06/passengerenabled-off-not-working.html) prevents you from turning it off.

Or, switch to using `libapache2-mod-php5filter` and fiddle with it until apache gets it to run as an output filter after passenger handles the request and outputs php code.

Comment: I removed passenger completely and the behavior is still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what went wrong because as I was fixing things, Chrome kept on showing me a download of the PHP file. It still does, while other browsers shows the PHP being executed. Is Chrome using some cache? Anyway, since I asked the question, the only missing part was installing php5-mysql.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to fix this problem on one of my servers.

Turns out it is caused by "bad" filename matching somewhere. I renamed default index.html with that "It works!" text to index.html.bak. No problem, right? Turns out that apache was actually serving that .bak file instead of index.php.